# Progress Bar using Background worker between two different classes

Tags: c#, namespaces, backgroundworker

1. I work in visual studio (version 2010).
2. I'm trying to set up a progress bar in one form (different namespace and class) based on variables in another namespace and class.
3. The ProgressPerc variable you see in the code is from another class (which I already indicated with using 'OtherNameSpace'.
4. It tells me I can't convert ProgressPerc to int (as I cannot convert type tot int).

What would be the most optimal solution here? I would like to use this variable to indicate the progress of the simulations.

EDIT: added the ALMBerekeningen code. This is just a small part of it, the full code is too much to show here.

Thanks!

---

```
public class ALMBerekeningen
{
    public int sim;
    public int Progress;
    public double ProgressPerc;

    this.ProgressPerc = this.sim / 1000;
    this.Progress = (int)Math.Round(this.Progress * 100f, 0, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
}

Public class Form1: Form
{
    private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {

        ALMBerekeningen ProgressPerc;

        int sims;

        sims = (int)ProgressPerc;

        try
        {
            backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(sims);
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            backgroundWorker1.CancelAsync();
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
        lblProgress.Text = "Completed " + progressBar1.Value.ToString() + " %";
        progressBar1.Update();
    }
}
```

Comment: @Mong Zhu I added part of the code. this.sim is changed in ALMBerekeningen and goes from 1 to 1000.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass in the instance of `ALMBerekeningen` to the background worker when you start it and then access it using the `DoWorkEventArgs.Argument` property in the event handler:

```
public void Main()
{
     //The instance of the class with the variable for your progress bar
     ALMBerekeningen almBerekeningen = new ALMBerekeningen();

     BackgroundWorker bgw = new BackgroundWorker();
     bgw.DoWork += bgw_DoWork;

     //Pass your class instance in here
     bgw.RunWorkerAsync(almBerekeningen);
}


private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{

    //e.Argument is the instance of the class you passed in
    var progressPerc = (ALMBerekeningen)e.Argument;

    int sims;

    sims = progressPerc.ProgressPerc;

    try
    {
        backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(sims);
    }

    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        backgroundWorker1.CancelAsync();
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
}
```

Incidentally, your `DoWork` handler as shown will only execute one time.  I presume that you have just simplified it down for the sake of the example.

Comment: Maybe also worth noting that copied `catch` block is far from ideal.

Comment: "You need to pass in the instance of ALMBerekeningen to the background worker" you don't really need to do that, it would also work if it is a simple field in the `Form` class.